# Is there a way to downgrade a 2nd gen iPod touch from iOS 4 back to 3.1.3?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

Is there a way to downgrade an iPod touch (2nd gen) from iOS 4 back to 3.1.3?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways.

The first way was if you [backed up](http://www.saurik.com/id/12#howto) your SHSH blobs with Cydia. (you would know if you did this) During a software update, iTunes verifies the software with an Apple server to make sure it's a valid, Apple-approved release. With major upgrades now 3.x, 4.x, Apple has stopped signing older versions, so if you try to restore normally to an older SW version, the verification process will fail.

The tutorial above will register your specific device on Cydia's server, then force iTunes to verify there instead of Apple's servers. **Unfortunately, if you didn't back up before you upgraded, this will not work.**

The other option requires some terminal work and downloading [iRecovery](http://www.ihackintosh.com/2009/07/irecovery-iphone-recovery-mode-loop-restart/), but it's not so bad. [Here's](http://justanotheriphoneblog.com/wordpress/iphone-tips/quick-tip-downgrading-4-0-beta-to-3-1-3) a tutorial for it.

Comment: Your bold print is wrong. SHSH blobs only apply for reinstalling v4.0 up on a second gen iPod Touch.

Comment: Hmmm...I couldn't find anywhere online stating that. Everywhere I read says that for all models, you must back up your SHSH blobs in order to downgrade. Why is the 2nd Gen iPod different? And can you point me to a source please?

Comment: SHSH blobs were first introduced with the iPhone 3GS/Touch 3G. Older models don't have a hardware SHSH check. In iOS 4.0, Apple put in a software check for the Touch 2G and iPhone 3G, but this only affects installing the 4.0 firmware. http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/833937433/blob-banter

Answer (score 2):

On a second gen iPod Touch, just download the firmware (or find it if it is still on your system, but iTunes has a habit of deleting it), put your device into DFU mode, and shift-click restore on iTunes. A guide for DFU mode is available at [iClarified](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=1034)

Warning: You will lose all your data.

Comment: But once I tried tried to downgrade from iOS 4 to iOS 3.1.3 iTunes showed error 3194 and 10XX. I tried it more than 30 times with different versions of iTunes. Read a lot of guides, but none of them worked.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: Are you certain you are using a __second generation__ ipod touch? Otherwise you need a SHSH blob.

Comment: I am 100% sure that I have iPod Touch 2G, because I have been using it during 1.5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Whited00r](http://www.whited00r.com/iPodTouch2G). It's super easy:

- gives you iOS 3.1.3
- certain elements are skinned ala iOS 6
- it's fast/quick
- no SHSH blob requirements or any of that
- download the zip containing an IPSW
- option-click on Restore iPod in iTunes, select downloaded file
- enjoy
- [tweak to get rid of additional items](http://www.whited00r.com/post-installation#speedup)